# Spring boot, security starter and OAuth2 client

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot with web and security starter dependencies, and spring-security-oauth2. I'm trying to secure a REST API with a remote (Openstack Keystone) OAuth2 provider.

So far I've managed to correctly fetch an access_token but when it comes to getting the user information I get a 404 not found, as it seems that the OS provider expects the access_token to be provided in the request parameters.

I can't figure out how to persuade the `OAuth2RestTemplate` class to append the access_token to the `security.oauth2.client.resource.user-info-uri` endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that setting `security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme` to `query` will make the RestTemplate append the access_token to the subsequent requests for user information.